# Selecting images back to previous ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am working in xcode 6.4. I have a View which contain 5 UIImageView.I have given UITapGestureRecognizer(single tap) for each image.When clicking on each image,a CollectionView will appear using Navigation Controller.The CollectionView contains some images.When clicking on any images in the CollectionView,it should navigate to the previous ViewController and the image should be changed with the selected image.
How it is possible to pass images to previousViewController?(I am Using Objective-C)

Comment: See also: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html

Answer (score -1):

Create public property with UIImageView in you CollectionView controller. When you will navigate to CollectionView, make something like:

```
collectionVC.imageView = self.imageView;
```

then you can operate with imageView directly from CollectionView